# Mips array incrementation

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying to write MIPS code with 10 digit number getting average from each of 4 digits starting from the first digit. I am trying to increment the count of array as it calculates each time the loop occurs. I am lost on how to increment each count and how to store each average. Thank you.

Here is my code until now:

```
.data

array:  .word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
length: .word 4
sum:    .word 0
average:    .word 0

.text 
.globl main

.ent main

main:

    la $t0, array   #base address
    li $t1, 0       # i = 0
    lw $t2, length  #$t2 = length
    li $t3, 0       #sum = 0
    sumLoop:
        lw $t4, ($t0)   #$t4 = array[i]
        add $t3, $t3, $t4   #sum = sum + array[i]

        add $t1, $t1, 1 # i = i + 1
        add $t0, $t0, 4 # Upadting array address
        blt $t1, $t2, sumLoop   # if i < len, then loop again.
        sw $t3, sum


        # Calculate the average.
        div $t5, $t3, $t2   #ave = sum/length
        sw $t5, average

        #Display sum


    lw $a0, average
    addi $v0,$0, 1
    syscall
exit:
        li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Do you have an algorithm that works, e.g. a C program that does this?  If not, that's where to start, then translate it to MIPS.  If so, then share it with us, so we can help with the next step.

Comment: You're already incrementing a position counter `i` each time through the loop with `add $t1, $t1, 1`.  What more do you want your program to do?

Comment: I want to move the length of the array from 0 to 4, 1 to 5, 2 to 6 like this